# qt sdk 1.2.1 not possible to download anymore

Tags: qt, qt4

It seems that there is not possible to download qt sdk version from
http://qt-project.org/downloads
When i try to download the linux offline variant 64 bits  i will be redirect to

http://www.developer.nokia.com/dp?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fsw.nokia.com%2Fid%2F14b2039c-0e1f-4774-a4f2-9aa60b6d5313%2FQt_SDK_Lin64_offline

i become a member there but i can not download the sdk.
Does anyone knows any alternative place to download the qt sdk 1.2.1 for linux (or windows)

Comment: That's new.  If Nokia still have ownership of the SDK packaging (pure speculation) then you may have to download the libraries and Creator separately.

Comment: I voted to close. my mistake.

Comment: The SDK is not updated anymore. It's recommended to just download Qt and Creator. The SDK is only useful for mobile development (Symbian).

Comment: @user1520812 The SDK available http://www.developer.nokia.com/info/sw.nokia.com/id/da8df288-e615-443d-be5c-00c8a72435f8/Qt_SDK.html

Comment: @sara these days, that link just redirects to windows phone related downloads